# Object doesn't support #inspect with Mandrill

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mandrill

I'm trying to get the Mandrill API working with my Rails app but when I try test it in the console with this:

```
AdminMailer.new_attending(creator, user)
```

I get the following:

```
AdminMailer#new_attending: processed outbound mail in 1.8ms
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
=>
```

I was following the tutorial on how to integrate it from here: https://gorails.com/episodes/sending-emails-with-mandrill but I can't seem to find where the error is.

My Mailer code is:

```
class AdminMailer < ApplicationMailer

require 'mandrill'

 def mandrill_client
  @mandrill_client ||= Mandrill::API.new MANDRILL_API_KEY
 end

 def new_attending(creator, user)
  template_name = "new-attending"
  template_content = []
   message = {
   to: [{email: creator.email, name: creator.name}],
   subject: "Someone wants to go riding with you!",
   merge_vars: [
     {rcpt: creator.email,
     vars: [
       {name: "CREATOR_NAME", content: creator.name},
       {name: "USER_NAME", content: user.name},
       {name: "USER_NUMBER", content: user.number}
       ]}
   ]
 }
 mandrill_client.message.send_template template_name, template_content, message
end

end
```

User.rb model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
     :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

has_many :events

has_many :attending_events
has_many :attending, through: :attending_events, source: :event

has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },   :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

My event.rb model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user

has_many :attending_events
has_many :attendees, through: :attending_events, source: :user

end
```

Does anyone know where the problem might be coming from and how I can fix it? In the console I can get the creator.email, creator.name, user.name and user.number fine but when I try and get them in the mailer, it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: Comment you devise code for while and check this error is resolve or not

Answer (score -1):

you're not getting model data in **new_attending(creator,user)** method any where.

Remove sad code from your mailer use happy code as provided below :)

```
@mandrill = nil
def default
    require 'mandrill'
    @mandrill = Mandrill::API.new 'Enter your API Key'
end

def new_attending(creator_name,creator_email,user_name)
default
----your code --
end
```

In Event.rb add this.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

--
---
    def send_new_attending_mail_notification
         creator_name = self.name
         creator_email = self.email
         user_name = self.user.name
         AdminMailer.new.new_attending(creator_name,creator_email,user_name)
    end
end
```

Call this method from your event controller,

```
@event.send_new_attending_mail_notification
```

let me know if you face any problems in that.